# Application failed on Emulator to launch due to time-out

Tags: android, android-emulator, timeout

From past 1 hour,I am unable to launch my application on `Eclipse-Helios` and the console on my `Eclipse` gives the following error:

```
[2011-11-21 10:37:00 - PagingScrollerExample] Failed to install PagingScrollerExample.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2011-11-21 10:37:00 - PagingScrollerExample] Launch canceled!
```

I had come across the same problem before,but whenever I perform `Project->Clean` process I could overcome this sort of problem.But today I don't know what has happened.I performed the `Clean` process and uninstalled the same application on my `Emulator` which was running before as well.

Could anyone sort out this problem for me and most importantly I would like to know what would be the reason for this?

I am using `Android-2.2` as a target for this application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may have to increase the ADB connection time out. In the Eclipse--> Preferences--> Android---> DDMS, increase the ADB connection time out to 10000. By default it would be 5000.

[image]

Please try this. Hope it would help.

Comment: That's right.I was searching the whole eclipse for this, which was driving me nuts.Thanks Amy88 :)

Comment: I tried this, but not working... I changed the time to 100 seconds but still jot working.... now it waits for 100 secs and then shows the timeout error

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your emulator. and launching it again.. i know its tedious process.. but it works.. :)