# Can not increase connection timeout

Tags: android, connection-timeout, timeoutexception

I want to increase timeout to 5 minutes because one minute is not enough to receive response.

I ahve tried this two approaches:

```
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 80000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 80000);



        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            createRequest();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            final int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        AndroidDefaultClient client = AndroidDefaultClient.newInstance("tets");
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 5* 60 *1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 5* 60 *1000);
```

Unfortunatly the timeout remains the same, but in case when I make it smaller, e.g. 10000, it works fine. Could you please help me to figure out with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc is incorrect on this point. The default connection timeout is platform-dependent, around a minute, and cannot be increased, only decreased.

Comment: Wow! Could you provide link on some article that can describe it in more details?

Comment: My source is Stevens & Wright, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* Volume 2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on an emulator? Perhaps you need to increase the adb connection timeout as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207589/application-failed-on-emulator-to-launch-due-to-time-out).

Or you might need to re-order your params and client code to have the params come first as talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730078/android-androidhttpclient-how-to-set-timeout).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the real device - Ssmung Galaxy Tab. I will try your second solution

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help

08-13 18:31:58.269: D/s(7463): LoginCommand command is finished after -60667 ms